# PL/SQL. Parse clob UTF8 chars with regexp_like regular expressions

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

I want to check if any line of my clob have strange characters like (Ã±§). These characters are read from a csv-file with an unexpected encoding (UTF-8) which converts some of them.

I tried to filter each line using a regular expression but it's not working as intended. Is there a way to know the encoding of a csv-file when read?

How could I fix the regular expression to allow lines with only these characters? `a-zA-Z 0-9 .,;:"'()-_&` space tab.

Clob example readed from csv:

```
  l_clob clob :='
"exp","objc","objc","OBR","031110-5","S","EXAMPLE","NAME","08/03/2018",,"122","3","12,45"
 "xp","objc","obj","OBR","031300-5","S","EXAMPLE","NAME","08/03/2018",,"0","0","0"
';
```

Another clob:

```
DECLARE
    l_clob   CLOB
        := '"exp","objc","objc","OBR","031110-5","S","EXAMPLE","NAME","08/03/2018",,"122","3","12,45"
             "xp","objc","obj","OBR","031300-5","S","EXAMPLE","NAME","08/03/2018",,"0","0","0"';
    l_offset             PLS_INTEGER := 1;
    l_line               VARCHAR2 (32767);
    csvregexp   CONSTANT VARCHAR2 (1000)
        := '^([''"]+[-&\s(a-z0-9)]*[''"]+[,:;\t\s]?)?[''"]+[-&\s(a-z0-9)]*[''"]+' ;
    l_total_length       PLS_INTEGER := LENGTH (l_clob);
    l_line_length        PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN

    WHILE l_offset <= l_total_length
    LOOP
        l_line_length := INSTR (l_clob, CHR (10), l_offset) - l_offset;

        IF l_line_length < 0
        THEN
            l_line_length := l_total_length + 1 - l_offset;
        END IF;

        l_line := SUBSTR (l_clob, l_offset, l_line_length);

        IF REGEXP_LIKE (l_line, csvregexp, 'i')
        THEN                                   -- i (case insensitive matches)
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Ok');
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_line);
        ELSE
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Error');
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_line);
        END IF;

        l_offset := l_offset + l_line_length + 1;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: A simple regex to allow only ASCII is `^[ -~]*$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to allow special characters you can use this regex:

#### Your Regex

```
csvregexp   CONSTANT VARCHAR2 (1000) := '^[a-zA-Z 0-9 .,;:"''()-_&]+$' ;
```

#### Regex-Details

- `^` Start of your string - no chars before this - prevents partial match
- `[]` a set of allowed chars
- `[]+` a set of allowed chars. Has to be one char minimum up to inf. (* instead of + would mean 0-inf.)
- `[a-zA-Z]+` 1 to inf. letters
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` 1 to inf. letters and numbers
- `$` end of your string - no chars behind this - prevents partial match

I think you can work it out with this ;-)

If you know there could be an other encoding in your input, you could try to convert and check against the regex again.

#### Example-convert

```
select convert('täst','us7ascii', 'utf8') from dual;
```

Comment: Thanks, but there are too many encoding posibles in the input files so I will filter with a regex similar to that even if some of the chars are wrong.